# making a custom installable theme package

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, design-packages

I have completed developing my custom theme in magento and now I want to make it installable or I want to package my design like other magento themes so that I can just put it in htdocs and go through the installation steps to install that custom theme. Can any body provide me a clue on how to make the custom theme installable?

Comment: Do you have any example of this?

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension) is what you are looking. Themes are packed just like extensions to be installed with Magento Connect.
The link i posted is the official guide to pack extensions and themes in Magento.